# Variable names in Grunt folders for WebP

Tags: gruntjs

I'd like to convert all my images to WebP so I can optionally show WebP with a fallback.  Here is the grunt for it: https://github.com/somerandomdude/grunt-webp

But I have a solid folder structure for my images so they are easy to find and for maintenance.

```
images/slider/
images/header/
images/people/
```

stuff like that.  Is there a way to add a variable to src/dest so that the dest will retain it's folder structure?

Comment: If `grunt-webp` adheres to grunt conventions then it should be possible to add `expand: true` and `cwd: 'images/'` to the `files` object of your `webp` task in  _Gruntfile.js_ (see further info [here](https://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically)). For instance: `files: { expand: true, cwd: 'images/', src: '**/*.{png,jpg}', dest: 'dist/images/' },` _Note: You may need to change the globbing pattern part (i.e. `**/*.{png,jpg}`) to include more file extensions that `grunt-webp` can transform to `.webp`. You may also need to set `ext: '.webp'` in `files` object too_

Comment: I understand that, my problem is I want `dest: 'dist/images'` to be `'images/x/y/z'` depending on the `src`.  Does that make sense?  I want the new images to be in the same place as the old images, they have a different extension so it won't cause any problems with overwriting.